# Why turnSpeedMouse error?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Why is this code doesn't work? I fixed the quotes, but I get an error message in the console:

[image]

Te script from here: https://medium.com/@verochan/how-to-make-a-360%C2%BA-image-viewer-with-unity3d-b1aa9f99cabb

How can I fix this?
Thank you very much in advance!

```
float horizontal;
float vertical;
Transform container;
void LateUpdate () 
{
    //Using mouse
    horizontal = Input.GetAxis(“Mouse X”);
    vertical= Input.GetAxis(“Mouse Y”);

    //This is made in order to avoid rotation on Z, just by typing 0 on Zcoord isn’t enough
    //so the container is rotated around Y and the camera around X separately
    container.Rotate(new Vector3(0, horizontal*(-1), 0f)*Time.deltaTime*turnSpeedMouse);
    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(vertical, 0, 0)*Time.deltaTime*turnSpeedMouse);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial forgot to declare the `turnSpeedMouse` variable and this is very likely a float.

```
public float turnSpeedMouse = 50f;
```

The whole code should look like this:

```
public float turnSpeedMouse = 50f;
float horizontal;
float vertical;
Transform container;

void LateUpdate () 
{
    //Using mouse
    horizontal = Input.GetAxis(“Mouse X”);
    vertical= Input.GetAxis(“Mouse Y”);

    //This is made in order to avoid rotation on Z, just by typing 0 on Zcoord isn’t enough
    //so the container is rotated around Y and the camera around X separately
    container.Rotate(new Vector3(0, horizontal*(-1), 0f)*Time.deltaTime*turnSpeedMouse);
    transform.Rotate(new Vector3(vertical, 0, 0)*Time.deltaTime*turnSpeedMouse);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But now I see another error message:   
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
CameraController.LateUpdate () (at Assets/CameraController.cs:22)

Comment: You need to initialize `container` variable. Just put `container = GameObject.Find("cameraContainer").transform` in the `Start` function. Note that "cameraContainer" is the name if the Object you created in step 3 from that tutorial. Any other problem you have from here should be a new question since they have nothing to do with the original question.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!